# Extract value from input element string array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have an string array read from `<td>` of a `datatable` like this

```
"<input id=\"item_Job_ID\" name=\"item.Job_ID\" type=\"text\" value=\"5036\">"
```

how can i get only the value from it in c#.

i tried `Split("\\")`  which doesn't work. can i use `linq` to extract the value ?

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Don't parse HTML/XML with regular expressions or string processing!

Comment: @Sham As far as I understand, he wants 5036

Comment: Its better to save this value in json in db, If you have option to edit the current implementation

Comment: Use [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) to parse html.

Comment: @sham yep its 5036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, It's work for you

```
 string inputstr = "< input id =\"item_Job_ID\" name=\"item.Job_ID\" type=\"text\" value=\"5036\">";
 var splitdataList = inputstr.Split(new string[] { "\"", "=", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
 var value = splitdataList.Contains("value") ? splitdataList[splitdataList.IndexOf("value") + 1] : ""; // Return 5036
```

Answer (score 1):

use Html Agility Pack.

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 string htmlContent = "<input id=\"item_Job_ID\" name=\"item.Job_ID\" type=\"text\" value=\"5036\">";
 doc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);
 HtmlNode inputNode = doc.DocumentNode.FirstChild;
 string value = inputNode.GetAttributeValue("value", "0");
```